# How to run a python file with the click of a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am making a menu screen for a game and want to open the main game screen using a python file when you click the button.

This is the button code:

```
Play = Button(root, text="PLay(Bot)", fg="blue", bg="cyan", command=open)
```

and the game file path is (C:\Users\PCCF(HOFF)\PycharmProjects\RPS pythonGUI\GAME.py)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import subprocess
Play = Button(t, text="PLay(Bot)", fg="blue", bg="cyan", 
              command=lambda:subprocess.Popen(args=['python', r'C:\Users\PCCF(HOFF)\PycharmProjects\RPS pythonGUI\GAME.py'])))
```

Comment: will this still work if I close the opened window manually and then click the button again?

Comment: Yes, It will run the Game many times as you click on the button.